# No audio in video recording (using GPUImage) after initializing The Amazing Audio Engine

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, gpuimage, the-amazing-audio-engine

I'm using two third party tools in my project. One is ["The Amazing Audio Engine"](https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine). I use this for audio filters. The other is GPUImage, or more specifically, [GPUImageMovieWriter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/iOS/GPUImageMovieWriter.m). When I record videos, I merge an audio recording with the video. This works fine. However, sometimes I do not use The Amazing Audio Engine and just record a normal video using GPUImageMovieWriter. The problem is, even just after initializing The Amazing Audio Engine, the video has only a fraction of a second of audio at the beginning, and then the audio is gone.

```
+ (STAudioManager *)sharedManager
{
    static STAudioManager *manager = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (!manager)
        {
            manager = [[STAudioManager alloc] init];
            manager.audioController = [[AEAudioController alloc] initWithAudioDescription:[AEAudioController nonInterleaved16BitStereoAudioDescription] inputEnabled:YES];
            manager.audioController.preferredBufferDuration = 0.005;
            manager.audioController.voiceProcessingEnabled = YES;
            manager.audioController.useMeasurementMode = YES;
        }
    });
    return manager;
}
```

Something is happening when TAAE is initialized. My suspicion is it's something having to do with AVAudioSession as it's a sharedInstance. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: i want to need your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625275/save-video-buffer-which-is-playing-with-youtube-ios-player-helper-pods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally when I finally buckle and post a question, I find my problem.

Setting the preferredBufferDuration to 0.005 is a bit excessive. Removing this line solved my problem.

You can learn more about preferredBufferDuration [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/OptimizingForDeviceHardware/OptimizingForDeviceHardware.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW2).